# Expected validator to return Promise or Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-forms, angular-validation

I'm trying to do a custom validation on Angular 5 but I'm facing the following error

```
Expected validator to return Promise or Observable
```

I just want to return an error to the form if the value doesn't match the required, here's my code:

This is the component where my form is

```
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private cadastroService:CadastroService) {
    this.signUp = fb.group({
      "name": ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])],
      "email": ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      "phone": ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])],
      "cpf": ["", Validators.required, ValidateCpf]
    })     
   }
```

This code is in the file with the validation I want to implement:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidateCpf(control: AbstractControl){
    if (control.value == 13445) {
        return {errorCpf: true}
    }
    return null;
}
```

Does that type of validation only work with observables or can I do it without being a promise or observable?

Answer (score 618, accepted):

It means that you have to **add multiple validators in array**

.
Example:

**With Error**

```
profileFormGroup = {
  budget: [null, Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]
};
```

Above one throws error that **validator to return Promise or Observable**

**Fix:**

```
profileFormGroup = {
  budget: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]]
};
```

**Explanation:**

In angular Reactive form validation done by using in-built validators which could given in array in 2nd postion, when **multiple validators used**.

> FIELD_KEY: [INITIAL_VALUE, [LIST_OF_VALIDATORS]]

Comment: Interestingly, I completely missed the brackets around the validators from the accepted/popular answer. You did well pointing out both the issue and the solution.

Comment: Your first point is the correct answer.. This answer should be marked right.

Comment: shame on angular guys! the problem is not observable at all, it is array syntax

Comment: Perfect...the first line itself solves my issue

Comment: Adding brackets around multiple validators did the trick, thanks!

Comment: I would not have figured it out without this post!

Answer (score 51):

The following should work :

```
  "cpf": ["", [Validators.required, ValidateCpf]]
```

the arguments the form control expects are the following :

```
constructor(formState: any = null, 
            validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null,
            asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null)
```

from https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Answer (score 16):

I think it is good to clarify in addition to the accepted answer that the error happens because when using reactive forms for creating a FormControl, after the initial_value the following arguments are, respectively, synchronous validators and async validators grouped in the form of an array each. E.g:

```
myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    myControl: ['', [ mySyncValidators ], [ myAsyncValidators ] ]
})
```

If the control happens to have just one of either, Angular accepts it as a single element. E.g.:

```
myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    myControl: ['', mySyncValidator, myAsyncValidator ]
})
```

Therefore, when forgetting about the brackets for grouping them Angular assumes the second validator item is part of the Async validators and so we get the `Expected validator to return Promise or Observable`

Answer (score 12):

You surely defined multiple validators in your reactive form.

wrong :

```
'status': [false,,[Validators.required]]
```

I just used two commas **(,)** after defining the value of status false.

Right :

```
 'status': [false,[Validators.required]]
```

Answer (score 9):

This type of error usually occurs if u do something like this -

```
name: ['',Validators.required, Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(3),Validators.maxLength(15)])]
```

Change this to -

```
name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3),Validators.maxLength(15)])]
```

2nd field -> validators

Answer (score 8):

If you add multiple validators, then you need to add another third bracket '[]' and inside that, you should put your validators. Like Below:

```
this.yourForm= this.formBuilder.group({
    amount: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)]],
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Not directly related to the OP's question, but I got the same error on a slightly different problem. I had an async validator, but I forgot to return an Observable (or Promise) from it.

Here was my original async validator

```
public availableEmail(formControl: FormControl) {
   if(formControl && formControl.value){
     return this.http.get('')
   }
}
```

The thing is, what if the if-statement is false? We do not return anything, and we get a runtime error. I added the return type (making sure the IDE complains if we do not return the correct type), and then I return `of(true)` in case the if-sentence fails.

Here is the updated async validator.

```
public availableEmail(formControl: FormControl): Observable<any> {
   if(formControl && formControl.value){
     return this.http.get('someUrl');
   }
   return of(true);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Error:**
 `"cpf": ["", Validators.required, ValidateCpf]`

**Fix:**
 `"cpf": ["", [Validators.required, ValidateCpf]]`

Answer (score 1):

Validators.compose() is redundant;

You can just pass an array. OP’s problem is caused by failure to wrap the validators in [] to make them an array, hence the minLength() one is assumed to be async and the resulting error message.

I hope, this solution will help you. Thanks.

Comment: yeah. I used Validators.compose([]). it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

error: 
 userName:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3)],forbiddenNameValidator(/password/)],

ans:
 userName:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3),forbiddenNameValidator(/password/)]],

validators use only second parameter in inside array. not for outside array

Comment: “This may not provide answer to the question. Please add proper explanation. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.”

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had this code that had the same issue

```
if (this.formGroup.get('client').value) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  return this.usersService.isOrgNameDuplicate(ctrl.value, this.formGroup.get('client').value).pipe(
    map((res) => (this.duplicateLogicCheck(res, ctrl))),
    catchError(() => of(null))
    );
}
return null;
```

**The fixed version**

```
if (this.formGroup.get('client').value) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  return this.usersService.isOrgNameDuplicate(ctrl.value, this.formGroup.get('client').value).pipe(
    map((res) => (this.duplicateLogicCheck(res, ctrl))),
    catchError(() => of(null))
    );
}
return of(null);
```

Note: changed `return null` to `return of(null)`