# Even after submitting valid values in angular fields submit button remains disabled

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying enable the login button based on the email validations using angular's Validators.email. However, even after entering all the required fields the button is not getting enabled.
I also tried using validators.minlength but there as well I am facing the same challenge.
Thank you in advance for the help.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,  FormBuilder,  Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.submitForm();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  submitForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
       name: ['', Validators.required, Validators.email ],
       password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  get name(){
    return this.myForm.get('name');
  }

}
```

```html
<div fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlexFill class="main-div">
<mat-card fxFlex="25">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">LogIn Page</mat-toolbar>
    <form fxLayoutAlign="stretch" fxLayout="column" class="login-form" [formGroup]="myForm">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>User Name</mat-label>
          <input FormControlName="name" matInput placeholder="name">
        </mat-form-field>
      
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input matInput FormControlName="password" placeholder="password" type="password">   
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid"  routerLink="/mainPage">LogIn</button>
      </form>
</mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: You've posted ts content twice, please post html part.

Comment: Hi @MishaMashina thanks for noticing that. Added the html part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of small issues in the code.

**First,** in `.ts` component, multiple validators should be group in as an array `[]`.
The second argument of `form control` is for sync validators while the third argument is for async validators. So if you don't group them by `[]`, you're telling your `formControl` that `Validators.email` is an `async` validator *(which it is not)* due to it being separated by a comma`,`.

Reference: [Expected validator to return Promise or Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548062/expected-validator-to-return-promise-or-observable)

So your `submitForm()` function should be like this:

```js
  submitForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
       name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email] ],
       password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

**Secondly** in `HTML` component, a small typo due to which form controls are not bonded correctly. Form Controls in the Form Group are written as `formControlName` and not `FormControlName`, so your HTML should be like this:

```html
 <form fxLayoutAlign="stretch" fxLayout="column" class="login-form" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <mat-form-field>
       <mat-label>User Name</mat-label>
       <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="name">
    </mat-form-field>
      
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="password" placeholder="password" type="password">   
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid"  routerLink="/mainPage">
    LogIn</button>
 </form>
```